# Alignment of my columns

Tags: python, output, vertical-alignment

I had to create a program that had a user enter the volume of a cup that had a diameter of 3.5 inches.Then have it output the volume in 1 column and the height in another. The only thing i am stuck on now is aligning the height column.  Any ideas?

> for i,j in zip(h,oz):
>
> > print(j,i)

I get this output

```
4 0.416
8 0.832
12 1.248
16 1.664
20 2.08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
for i,j in zip(h,oz):
    print '{0: <3} {1: < 3}'.format(i, j)

4    0.416
8    0.832
12   1.248
16   1.664
20   2.08
```

see [Format Specification Mini-Language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for details

Comment: This worked thank you! But how exactly does this work I know that you have to convert the number into a string to get the .format to work. But how is the conversion implemented through the code above? Also I would upvote you but i don't have enough rep lol

Comment: No, you don't have to convert object to string explicitly to use format. Have to check, but i think that str or repr function called inside it

Comment: Numbers always have to be converted to strings to be displayed. The could be displayed as a string of decimal digits, sign, decimal point, etc. Or they could be displayed as a string of 0's and 1's, hexadecimal digits, or they could even be represented as letters, spaces, etc., e.g. twenty three.

The formatting makes the conversion to fit what you would like - don't expect it to give you twenty three though :)